# cannot pop mulitple pages with returning value

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project which need to from page1 push to page2 push to page3 push to page 4. In page 4, I have a button which will go back to page 1 and want to call API to refresh the data and display the new data on screen. However when I pop back to page 1, it seems cannot refresh the screen. I saw some solution is that I need to pass a true to the first page then trigger the fresh function. Please correct me if I am wrong

page1:

```
final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Page2(),
      ),
    );

    if (result != null && result) {
      onRefresh(); //this cannot trigger when page3>page1
    }
```

page2:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => page3()),
        ModalRoute.withName("/"));
```

page3:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. To refresh the data on page 1 when you pop back to it from page 4, you need to pass a true to it. You can do this by calling `Navigator.pop()` with a second argument of `true`.

Here is an updated example of your code:

```
// page1.dart
final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => Page2(),
  ),
);

if (result != null && result) {
  onRefresh();
}

// page2.dart
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => Page3(),
  ),
  ModalRoute.withName("/"),
);

// page3.dart
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

This will ensure that the `onRefresh()` function is called on page 1 when you pop back to it from page 4.

Another way to do this is to use a state management library such as GetX or Riverpod. With these libraries, you can create a global variable that indicates whether or not the data on page 1 needs to be refreshed. Then, you can listen to changes to this variable and update the data on page 1 accordingly.

Here is an example of how to do this using GetX:

```
// app.dart
final _refreshData = RxBool(false);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

// home_screen.dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shouldRefreshData = Get.find<_refreshData>();

    if (shouldRefreshData.value) {
      // Refresh the data on page 1.
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: // ...
      ),
    );
  }
}

// page2.dart
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: // ...
      ),
    );
  }
}

// page3.dart
class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 3'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: // ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, we have created a global variable called `_refreshData` using the `RxBool` class from GetX. This variable is initially set to `false`.

In the `HomeScreen` widget, we are listening to changes to the `_refreshData` variable. If the variable is set to `true`, then we refresh the data on page 1.

In the Page3 widget, we are setting the _refreshData variable to true when the user pops back to page 1. This will ensure that the data on page 1 is refreshed when the user returns to it.

You can use a similar approach with Riverpod to refresh the data on page 1 when you pop back to it from page 4.

Happy coding :)